# Iteratively replace a string inside a file

Tags: bash, replace, iteration

I have a file containing multiple entries for the same data, but the names are all the same. Every time a new entry starts, it has the same name as the previous one. I wanted to replace the name by itself plus an integer inside the file, signalizing the entry number in the file. This way, i would be able to extract the information inside using the code below with the unique names.

```
OLDIFS=${IFS}
IFS='%'
n=0
while read line ; do
  if [ ${n} == 0 ] ; then
    name=${line}
    n=1
    echo ${line} > ${name}.dat
  else
    echo ${line} >> ${name}.dat
  fi

  if [ "${line}" == '$$$$' ] ; then 
    n=0
  fi
done <file.dat

IFS=${OLDIFS}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for sharing the code you've tried so far. Please also share a sample of your input data and the exact expected output. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some excellent guidance.

Comment: a sample input file and expected output is worth more than 1000 words explanation.

Comment: Do you know that the `{ }` around the variable names are not required here, or do you just enjoy typing `{ }`?  They are not doing any harm, it just seems unnecessary.  Also, `name=${line}` is not the same as `name="$line"`